# Unable to understand sentence in the book of operating system

Tags: unix, process, operating-system

"The events depicted are artificial in that processes do not always experience them, but they illustrate various state transitions."

I am unable to understand the perfect meaning of this sentence. I assume this is because of I am not native English speaker or I don't have much experience about processes and their states. What the above sentence tries to convey? Is it saying that The process which is first time experiencing the state will consider it as artificial or some thing more. Kindly guide me so that I am able to clear what is the meaning of this sentence. Following is the some more information about the line. Following will help you to find the line in book if you want to read the other sentences with this sentences.

Name of the Book: "The Design of the UNIX operating system"
Author : "M.J.Bach"
Chapter : " 6 - The Structure of Processes"
Page number : "147"
Topic : "6.1 - Process states and transitions"
paragraph number : "2 from the beginning of the page"
Line number related to paragraph : "2 line in paragraph."

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of Bach handy at the moment, so I may be a bit off base on what I remember, but I think what it is trying to say is that it may help conceptually to think of a process going from state A to state B and then to state C, but a real-world OS may choose to go directly from A to C and just perform the steps for both transitions at once, because there may not be any real reason to actually have a state B and allow processes to live in that state.

Comment: It also means that not every process will encounter every state that the diagram lists as a possible state.